# Linq to Entities & WPF - save only entities related to a view

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, save, instance

**[EDITED]**

I am looking for a way to implement Linq To Entities in a WPF (MVVM) application and make each View (or ViewModel) responsible to manage their underlying entities separately.

Here is an example of a simple structure and what I would like to achieve:

[**Customers**] (1..1)  <---->  (0..* ) [**Orders**] (0..* )  <-- [**OrderLine**] -->  (1..* ) [**Product**]

**First view** displays the list of customers

- loads all the customers but not their orders
- allows to Create or Delete customers

**Second view** displays the detail of a customer and the list of its orders

- allows to Update the properties of the customer
- loads all the orders of a specific customer, but not the orderLines
- allows to Create or Delete orders
- there might be several views managing separately several customers.

**Third view** displays the detail of an order and the list of order lines

- allows to Update the properties of the order
- loads all the orderLines of a specific order, **and all products related to these orderLines**
- allows to Create or Delete orderLines
- there might be several views managing separately several orders.

**Fourth view** displays the detail of a product

- allows to Update the properties of the product
- the related product might already be loaded by the third view
- there might be several views opened at the same time and managing separately their own products. **I do not want to update all the products at once but only the related product of the view.**

According to Microsoft's recommendation, there must be one DbContext instance per view instance (or viewModel instance) (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx).

The above scheme is of course very simplified. In the real application we will have much more entities and views. Aditionaly their might be different flows in which the views are opened, making it difficult to know in advance which entities are already loaded from the database when a new view is opened.

Still, there is one principle: a view (or the corresponding ViewModel) should be responsible to update the set of entities that it displays, without asking the DbContext to update entities handled by another view.

QUESTIONS

1. The DbContext of the productView should be able to push changes on the related product to the database. However, it should not load the product from the database if it was already loaded previously (i.e. by the DbContext associated to the orderLinesView). The problem is that a DbContext, as I understand it, encapsulates a transaction which makes me think it can hardly be responsible of saving entities that it didn't load by itself proviously. How to address such issue?
2. It is pretty clear that I must have a DbContext instance per view instance so that SaveChanges() only process the data of the current view. What is unclear is weather I should have several classes that inherits DbContext or a single class representing the DbContext of the application.
3. Is it necessary to add a DbSet<> property on the DbContext for each entitity type we want to update? That seems like the DbContext will need to change all the time as the application grows with new entities. Additionaly, that means repetitive code in the viewModels to point out which DbSet<> should be loaded, etc. 
   Wouldn't it be more efficient to have a mechanism (1) that can receive a set of entities to update (no matter their type), and another mechanism (2) that allows to select a set of entities to pass to mechanism (1)? The second mechanism could be either manual (for flexible scenarios) or automatic (by looking all the entities listed in a ViewModel for example).
4. If I want to put the database access mechanism in a web service, how can I continue to manage their underlying entities of each view separately ? In such case, where and how the DbContexts should be instantiated?

I look forward to any advices you can give.

Comment: If you keep modifying the same instance of the object then you'll only be saving that one instance.  If you keep making new instances of your entities and then adding them to the context, then they'll save when you call SaveChanges on your context.  Are you actually saving duplicates to your database currently, or is this a theoretical question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be implementing something like the [Unit of Work and Repository Pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

This way you can keep the changes performed to the database as part of a work (window in your case) separated from the others. If you use the same context for all this is going to be complicated.

EDIT: trying to answer some of your questions:

1) As long as the next view doesn't alter the entities from other views you can pass the DTOs to it for logic on them. However this could cause some concurrency issues if the data you based your login on has changed. There is no easy way on working around this without saving all the entities related in one go. You can try to create your own cache and use it instead of querying the DbContext in those scenarios, but again this could be a problem with multiple users.

2 and 3) Have a look at the Unit of Work and Repository patterns I mentioned above. This should make a nice wrapper to avoid duplicating code.

4) For web service you should create a DbContext per each request, otherwise you could end up again with concurrency problems. Having a cache here could improve performance too.

Comment: Although adding an additional layer of abstraction with this pattern can help in leading to a solution to OP's question, this is not actually an answer to the question being asked.

Comment: That's right, but I think the problem comes from him using the same db context instance for manipulating the entities from different windows. So when one of the windows try to save it saves the entities modified by other windows as well. The answer will be "don't share the DbContext", but I thought it was more useful to point him as well to a well known pattern that handle that problem, along others.

Comment: True, but unless I'm misunderstanding the question it isn't a case of using multiple context objects.  OP sounds like they are just adding additional instances of entity objects to the context.

Comment: Lets wait for him to clarify then, I think its just that each view is using the same context. But I could be wrong!

Comment: Yeah, this could go either way depending on OP's response.  I think we need more info.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I'm sorry if I asked a trivial question but I'm new to Linq To entities. I thought I could have only one datacontext and then manage each entity separately, but if I understand you well, it doesn't work this way.
So rather, I should inherit one dbContext class per windows' type (for example : StudentView<->StudentDbContext,  SchoolView<->SchoolDbContext, etc), instantiate a new dbContext each time I instantiate a new window, and then call SaveChanges() & dispose() when the window closes.Once you confirm this is a good solution,I will reformulate my first post.

Comment: You can use the same class, just different instances for each, but that sounds like a good approach.

Comment: I am very sorry for for the long time without answer. I had to be out of the project for a while. I now updated my first post by giving a concrete example. It would be nice if you could have a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried to answer your questions @MaximeMax Give me a shout if you need more details on the answers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Only point I don't understand well is how the unit of work pattern may help my case. The dbContext itself is already a Unit Of Work and the dbset are already repositories, so I don't see how adding an abstraction layer will help my question 2) and 3).